# p5.js Add a dissapearing ellipse trail to Lissajous curve line

Tags: p5.js, curve

I have a simple code that traces the Liss cruve with a small ellipse. I was wondering how to add a **fading trail** to this shape so it represents the cruve more clearly. I only know a bit about adding trails that follows the mouse but I'm not sure how to do this one.

Any help is appreciated, here is the code:

```
var t = 0;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    fill(255);
    
}
    
function draw() {
    background(0);
 
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

       y = 160*sin(3*t+PI/2);
       x = 160*sin(1*t);
      
    fill(255);
    
    ellipse(width/2+x, height/2+y, 5, 5);
    t += .01;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `background(0)` to `background(0, 0, 0, 4)` :)

Here is a working example:

https://editor.p5js.org/chen-ni/sketches/I-FbLFDXi

## Edit:

Here is another solution that doesn't use the background trick:

https://editor.p5js.org/chen-ni/sketches/HiT4Ycd5U

Basically, it keeps track of each point's position and redraws them in every frame with updated alpha to create the "fading out" effect.

```
var t = 0;
var particleArray = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  
  y = width / 2 +  160 * sin(3 * t + PI / 2);
  x = height / 2 + 160 * sin(1 * t);

  particleArray.push(new Particle(x, y, t));
  
  for (i=0; i<particleArray.length; i++) {
    particleArray[i].show(t);
  }
  
  //keep the array short, otherwise it runs very slow
  if (particleArray.length > 800) {
     particleArray.shift();
  }
  
  t += .01;
}

function Particle(x, y, t) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.t = t;
  
  this.show = function(currentT) {
    var _ratio = t / currentT;
    _alpha = map(_ratio, 0, 1, 0, 255); //points will fade out as time elaps
    fill(255, 255, 255, _alpha);
    ellipse(x, y, 5, 5);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, is it possible to do this without altering the background? this is just a temporary background. The cruve is going to be on a 10 by 10 square grid..